# Is Onedrive.Appfolder the better option for programs to use?

Tags: onedrive

My application will be storing data on Onedrive. I will be recommending the user to unlinking sync of his onedrive from his machine. Is it possible for excluding Onedrive from syncing my application folder ? Will using onedrive.AppFolder help in any way ?